# My old iPad 2 has a persistent email virus "Virus Detected" that pops up whenever I attempt to use Safari

Tags: virus, phishing

I've attempted to delete the email, change the email and to close Safari but the email keeps returning and makes using the browser impossible. I have no intention of either calling the provided phone number or sending this email as it directs me to do. The email is as follows:

> Email addressed to: foo@example.com
>
> Subject: Warning! Virus Detected! Immediately Call Apple Support +1-800-876-6855. Your credit card details and banking information.Your e-mail passwords and other account passwords.Your Facebook, Skype, AIM, ICQ and other.Call Apple Support +1-800-876-6855. Your private photos, family photos and other sensitive files.Your webcam could be accessed remotely by stalkers with a VPN virus.
>
> message "Apple Tech Support !cc=bar@example.com"

How do I remove this ..... email, regain access to my browser and irradiate this virus from my iPad 2 which can no longer receive operating system and virus updates. This virus is not present on my new iPad Air 2, which I'm using to send this inquiry.

Comment: Try closing the browser from the multitasking view, then going to Settings -> Safari -> Clear history and data and see if that helps. If not try the same but disable the Wi-Fi first, and upon reopening Safari close all tabs before reconnecting to the network.

Comment: Finally consider installing a content blocker (Either Adblock Plus or 1Blocker) to block such crap in the future.

Comment: it's an email? in your browser?

Comment: Are you seeing this in the iPad email app or in the Safari browser? If the former, have you cleared your deleted items? If the browser, then is that really in an email or on a web page?

Comment: I thought Apple Devices couldn't get viruses? :p

Answer (score 1):

It is a little confusing that you say it is an email, but it is causing safari to become unusable. If you can clarify whether this is an email in apple mail app or a web page you cannot get rid of in safari (or an email appearing in a web interface email service) that would help.

follow the advice in the comment above regarding clearing of browser history.

If that still won't work, I would use the option within the settings menu to wipe the ipad and reset to factory defaults. However, make sure you apply iOS updates BEFORE you re-connect to your Apple ID as it is possible that the bad data has been uploaded to your iCloud account. The most important thing you need to do is get the iOS updates applied before any personal data is loaded onto your device.

If the problem persists, I would contact the real Apple support.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once, it is very easy to fix. Just make a link to some random website in notes or something then tap on it. You opened a new tab, then right after you do that, delete the tab that is preventing you from it, if you can't tell them apart, just delete all of the tabs